Asking a professor for review on paper draft before submitting to a journal
I have conducted independent research, and wrote a paper based on it, and want to ask the opionion of some expert before submitting it to a journal. I am contemplating whether I should ask someone or not.
I met a professor at a poster session who gave an impression that he is interested, he is an editor of the journal I want to send my work to.
Do you think I should ask for a professional opnion? Or does it look like a big favour, and I would put him into an awkward situation? I want to know if it is publishable and if this specific journal is suitable.
What would be a polite email template?

why did you conduct and 'independent research'? You did not have supervisor, or your supervisor failed to do the job? From what you write you need a mature and supportive supervisor, rather than editor comments. You may ask him to co-author and work with you on the manuscript...

@Intelligent-Infrastructure Nothing wrong in doing independent research, imho. And if the paper is ready, they do not need a co-author at this stage.

You can ask, worst he can say is no I am too busy.

Since you have already met him it is fine to ask for his opinion on your paper and whether it seems ready for submission.
Unless you have already corresponded a few times, remind him of your meeting.
I'll assume that this is also in his field. In this case it isn't such a big favor to ask.
I won't try to provide a template, but my method would be to ask if he is interested, sending only the abstract or introduction and a page count of the paper. I'd wait for confirmation before sending the paper.
Don't ask for an edit or corrections, but just his opinions. Let the journal or conference reviewers make editing suggestions after you submit. This way it doesn't read like you are asking for a co-author. I would avoid suggestions of that. If collaboration happens, let it be on future work. You might get a few suggestions for improvement in any reading whether you ask or not.

What kind of edits do journal reviewers do in CS/comp math? Grammatical only? or in the presentation style too?

Far more than that, actually. They will point out problems in your evidence/proof, for example. They will point you to other related work. Presentation and style would be the least of their concerns unless the paper is very poor.

Do they usually ask for codes in the first submission? Or if at all? @Buffy

That would depend on the paper and how necessary it is to evaluate the code in order to evaluate the paper. But they wouldn't ask for the code unless they ask for the code to be included in or linked by the paper.

A professor you ask, might want to see the code, however. But not journal reviewers except as noted above.

Firstly, people in a conference generally show interest. It is the objective of a conference to initiate discussions and collaboration. There is no guarantee they would follow through.
Personally, I do not ask for anything unless I could offer something back. Reviewing a paper is not easy and unless its a colleague I do not review papers of people I meet at a conference. People in general are busy.
Having said that you are within your rights to ask for a professional opinion. Mention in your email that you would like to send the paper to a journal in a week and his opinion would be invaluable. If they reply in a week, great, else go ahead and submit the paper. Let the formal reviewers read your paper and comment.
Congratulations on being able to do independent research. Best of luck with the paper.

"Personally, I do not ask for anything unless I could offer something back." The OP is a PhD student (going by their other posts). I don't think this is a good principle to apply to interactions between PhD students and senior scientists (like journal editors).

I was a PhD student once and  I followed the same principle. But maybe world is less transactional than I think it is or was :)

Here are some remarks:

Do you think I should ask for a professional opnion?

You could, but do not expect to have a full review of the paper.

Or does it look like a big favour, and I would put him into an awkward situation?

If you ask for a complete read of your paper, it might look awkward. Concerning asking for a favor, I wouldn't worry about it. In worst case you'll get a direct/polite refusal.

I want to know if it is publishable and if this specific journal is suitable.

Here are two main issues you point out:
a) You don't know yourself if the result is publishable or not. Some things are just not publication level, even though they "feel" new to someone. You should be familiar with the bibliography regarding the paper you wrote. If you are absolutely certain your work fills a gap and is genuinely new, then you will be able to publish it somewhere.
b) Learning if a specific journal is suitable can be done in a few steps:

read the scope of the journal. They will mention what subject the journal focuses on.

learn about the reputation of the journal. A top journal will only accept exceptional papers. Even a decent paper will be rejected there.

ultimately, you can submit your paper there, but you will find out the hard way (reject/accept) if the paper is suitable or not.


